# PHPEXCEL Get mysql column name in Single Row

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am working on application, where user upload their file (any format) and my application process it as per their use and DOWNLOAD IT.

I want to add Column name from mysql in single row but they are coming as follows:

name
mobile
city
Mick    9XXXXXXXX   Ahmedabad

my code as follows:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * from test_excel") or die(mysql_error());

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$row=1;

$q = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM test_excel");
if (mysql_num_rows($q) > 0) {
    while ($row_q = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        $col='A';
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($col.$row, $row_q['Field']);
        $col++;
    }
    $row++;
    }

while($row_data1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $col=0;
    foreach($row_data1 as $key=>$value){
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
        $col++;
    }
    $row++;
}

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel); 
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xls"');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Pls correct me where I am wrong.

PB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the column to A in each loop. Change it to this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($q) > 0) {
    $col='A';
    while ($row_q = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($col.$row, $row_q['Field']);
        $col++;
    }
    $row++;
}
```

**Also you should not use mysql functions as they are outdated. Look into [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.**